# selecting multiple unique columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                       'col2': ['B', 'A', 'A']})
df
```

How would I SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 from df?

Comment: Mayowa Ayodele. This worked thanks! I forgot to say that I also have col3, now if I do df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['col1','col2']), col3 also shows up but i only need col1 and col2

Comment: Thanks AccLok i actually want both columns simultaneously ^-^

Comment: I changed the answer to a list comprehension that returns a list of unique values from every column in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['col1','col2'])
```

Comment: both method worked thank you! the 2nd one returned an array but since i want to join with another df, I just used df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['col1','col2']) then removed col3 in a 2nd step so i am good ^-^ thank you again

Comment: @williamscathy825 Glad we could help! For your questions on SO, it would be great if you could up vote the answers you find informative/useful and accept the answer that best suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`[df[x].unique() for x in df.columns]` if you are looking for unique values from each column of your dataframe.